# HttpWebRequest causes Response does not start with HTTP.Data

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I am trying to use craigslist bulk posting by doing the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = null;
Uri uri = new Uri("https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/post");
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = FormattedXmlDocument.InnerXml.Length;
using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(FormattedXmlDocument.InnerXml);
    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
string result = string.Empty;

request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version11;
request.KeepAlive = false;
try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader readStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    // MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
}
```

When the this line of code is performed

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
```

I get the exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

I used fiddler to check the request and it get the following error there:

```
Response does not start with HTTP.Data:
```

and the pacakage looks like this:

```
POST https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/post HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: post.craigslist.org
Content-Length: 739
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cl="http://www.craigslist.org/about/cl-bulk-ns/1.0"><channel><items><rdf:li rdf:resource="TestJobPost1" /></items><cl:auth username="cl@flazingo.com" password="2749saturn" accountID="14" /></channel><item rdf:about="TestJobPost1"><cl:category>sof</cl:category><cl:area>nyc</cl:area><cl:subarea>stn</cl:subarea><cl:neighborhood>Grasmere</cl:neighborhood><cl:jobInfo compensation="100000.00" telecommuting="0" partTime="0" contract="0" nonprofit="0" internship="0" disability="0" recruitersOK="0" phoneCallsOK="0" okToContact="0" okToRepost="0" /><title>First Position</title><description><![CDATA[teset]]></description></item></rdf:RDF>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `FormattedXmlDocument.InnerXml.Length` is wrong; you need to call `encoding.GetByteCount()`.

Comment: changed to 'encoding.GetByteCount(FormattedXmlDocument.InnerXml);' but still getting the same result.

Comment: Try moving 
request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version11;
request.KeepAlive = false; above `GetRequestStream()`

Comment: what are you actually trying to post?

Comment: If you look in my question under "and the package looks like this:" <rdf:RDF xmls...  basically trying to post that.

Here is the reference:
http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface

Comment: 1. Moving the ProtocolVersion and KeepAlive above GetRequeststream() and 2. Changing the Version to Version10 gave me a Forbidden 403 error. Which I am going to take a good error based on: http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface

Comment: @SLaks if you like put in the answer, I would like to get you credit.

Comment: An XML file is not a content of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to `request.GetRequestStream()` will start sending data to the server.

Setting request properties after that will break the protocol.